# javafx: how to display custom class with a treeview

Tags: java, treeview, javafx, treeviewitem

I have a class like this

```
public class XMLTreeNode {

private ArrayList<XMLTreeNode> subnodes;
private String name;
private ArrayList<String> attrNames;
private ArrayList<String> attrValues;
}
```

and want to display it in a TreeView. Is there a better solution than writing a recursive method like `toTreeItem()` that converts it to a TreeItem that can set as root Element of the TreeView? 
In a TableView I used `SimpleStringProperty` to display the content, but I have no idea how that would work with a TreeView.

Thanks for any answer ;)